# Spring data - omitting IN operation if operand is empty

Tags: java, sql, spring-data

I have somewhat complicated query with List parameter in Spring Data repository, i.e.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select ... /* really_big_query */ ... where  ... and id IN (:ids)")
List<?> findSomething(@Param List<Long> ids)
```

I'd like to omit the condition if the parameter is empty (or else it will fail with SQL syntax error 'and id IN ()').

Unfortunately I cannot test it in the query such as:

```
and (:ids is null or id IN (:ids))
```

Duplicating the query method isn't good as the query is complicated. Rewriting native queries to specification is not an easy task either.

**How to test for empty IN operands in Spring Data?**

Comment: you can duplicate the query using a constant. And you should use constant for your queries.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? Even if I'd create a template constant, it is not possible to do anything dynamic within the annotation.

Comment: It's not possible to do what you want with the annotation. You should have 2 methods and create constant for your querie and use it in your annotation

Comment: I found a way by forcing a fake, unique value to the :ids , but it's not clean. `and ('FAKEVALUE' in (:ids) or id IN (:ids))`. Before executing the query, if your ids object is null, push the fake value to the list. That works if you can handle the dirty fakevalue.